how to parse json parameter file to semicolon separated string
I have this json file for parameters
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "code",
    "ParameterValue": "ab"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "env",
    "ParameterValue": "prod"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "api",
    "ParameterValue": "testapi"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "name",
    "ParameterValue": "new"
  }
]

how can I  parse this using jq into the following  output
code=ab;env=prod;api=testapi;name=new
tried to parse using jq but I am not getting the correct output as shown above
Thanks

Always share your attempt when asking a question, so that we can correct your code instead of writing code for you.

Try this:
jq 'map("\(.ParameterKey)=\(.ParameterValue)") | join(";")'

